# Page breaking in a glossing example environment

Tags: page-breaking, expex, gloss

I'm using the `expex` package for glossing exemples, and I have this giant example which doesn't want to break when the page ends. In the user's guide they say it should break automatcally but it doesn't. So it's not a problem in most of my examples (so far), but this one leaves almost a third of page empty, and I want it to split across pages

I tried to use `\eject`  or `\vfil\eject`, but it doesn't work.

Does someone know a solution?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}
\ex
\label{nat-wiol}
\begingl
\glpreamble {\tt NAT : dzień dobry \underline{pani wiolu} (...) to są właśnie te ankiety bardzo bym prosiła o wypełnienie (.) \underline{napiszcie} jakie \underline{macie} aspiracje jak \underline{wam} się tu pracuje jakie \underline{macie} oczekiwania wobec hotelu}//
\gla NAT : Dzień dobry \underline{Pani} \underline{Wiolu}. \nogloss{(...)}To są właśnie te ankiety, bardzo bym prosiła o wypełnienie. \underline{Napiszcie} jakie \underline{macie} aspiracje, jak \underline{wam} się tu pracuje jakie \underline{macie} oczekiwania wobec hotelu.//
\glb bon jour madame-{\sc voc} FN-{\sc voc} ce être-{\sc 3sg} justement ces enquêtes beaucoup {\sc part.cond.1sg} demander-{\sc pp} de compléter écrire-{\sc 2pl} quels avoir-{\sc 2pl} aspirations comment {\sc 2pl} {\sc .dat} {\sc pro.refl} ici travailler-{\sc 3sg} quels avoir-{\sc 3pl} attentes envers l'hôtel//
\glft'bonjour (madame) Wiola. Voilà les questionnaires, j'aimerai bien que vous les complétiez. Ecrivez quelles sont vos aspirations, est-ce que vous êtes bien ici, quelles sont vos attentes envers l'hôtel.'//
\endgl
\begin{flushright}
(JB-TA-pl.161)
\end{flushright}
\xe

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you complete the code snippet with the relevant packages?

Comment: @egreg, done! :)

Comment: As I understand it, ExPex will only break up subexamples (a,b,c); it will not break up glosses (and probably shouldn't). So  I think  what you should really do is insert manual breaks when needed at the very final stages of your document, and never break apart glosses.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to break it manually, and therefore I'm looking for a solution here. I've been trying different commands but it just doesn't work. The question is : what can I put in this environement to enable the exemple to spli? after the preamble, or before the translation, as you said, the glosses shoudn't be appart.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `expex` now supports page breaking of glosses with the `\glbreaking` command. If it doesn't, [contact John](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf) and he'll give you the file you need to implement the command.